# File in asset folder could run in webview, file in sd card could run in external browser, i want to run file in both webview and external browser

Tags: javascript, java, android, html, css

```
myWeb = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
myWeb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
myWeb.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
myWeb.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
    activity.setProgress(progress * 1000);
        }
    });

myWeb.loadUrl("/mnt/extSdCard/THEWEB/hi.html");
```

> //file:///android_asset/this.html    could run in webview but not in
>   externalbrowser ///mnt/extSdCard/THEWEB/hi.html   could run in
>   external but not in web view

```
File file=new File("/mnt/extSdCard/THEWEB/hi.html");
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.fromFile(file));
i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
i.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/x-webarchive-xml");
            startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

First option (/file:///android_asset/this.html) it works in the local browser because the file is located inside the package folders. This is private and it can't be accessed from outside, by other applications, including the external browsers.

The 2nd one as you wrote is to have the file in a shared folder, this works to be accessed from both the internal webview and the external one. In particular the problem for your code is the path:

```
"/mnt/extSdCard/THEWEB/hi.html"
```

it needs to be something like:

```
"file:///mnt/extSdCard/THEWEB/hi.html"
```

or even better you could use:

```
"file://"+Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/THEWEB/hi.html"
```

and your app should have the permissions added in the manifest to access the external storage:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: i have another question???

how can i make the user pick which browser he/she want to run the file for exmaple("opera mini", "google chrome", "internet browser"), i would like to do that, because sometimes , other cellphone has no default browser that is capable of running the file , ithanks in advance